# Angular directives of same type sharing method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In a view there are multiple directives of the same type. How can one execute a function, once the last directive has been compiled and linked?

**Details**:
There are multiple instances of the same directive. Say, for example special image tags which are loaded lazily. Now each directive instance is compiled and linked independently - the scope of them is the parent controller. Once all the directive instances have been compiled and linked, they need to be activated. (One could activate them independently during the linking phase, but I would like to activate them all together instead). I need this functionality in order to port a jquery plugin to angular.

Comment: you can use a parent directive to manage child directives.You can then communicate between the parent directive and the child directives. make the parent directive required and all the child directives register in some way to the parent directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each directive is compiled, keep a running count of the directives and add it to a list. The list is a variable stored within the directive itself.  When the list of registered directives matches the count of compiled directives, you know when the last directive has been linked, and you can execute your custom function.

**[See Plunker Demo Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cLLiqaAHPQNRg2WbAiZ9)**

```
  app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    var count = 0;
    var elements = [];
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function(element, attr) {
          ++count;
          return function(scope, element, attr) {
            elements.push(element);
            element.html('linking directive ' + elements.length);
            if (count == elements.length)
            {
              alert('linked all ' + elements.length + ' directives');
            }

          }
        }
    }

  });
```